# Is there a way to set a period of time with the PS Command "Add-MailboxPermission"?

Tags: powershell

Does someone know if it is possible to add a time period to this Powershell command:

```
Add-MailboxPermission -Identity user01@domain.com -User user02@domain.com -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All
```

So is there a way so I can give user02 accessright for the Mailbox of user01 from lets say 2022/11/20 up to 2022/11/25?

Comment: No. You need to track that manually.

Answer (score 0):

No.  The `Add-MailboxPermission` cmdlet does not accept any date-range parameters:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/add-mailboxpermission?view=exchange-ps

You could write a script to check the current date and run the appropriate `Add-` and `Remove-MailboxPermission` commands at the appropriate time.

(An alternate - but messy - approach is to create a temporary user account with access, setting an expiration date on the user account.  You'll need to mop up the account and permissions afterwards, though.)